# What does this mean exactly? $_SESSION['sessionName '][$item['rowName ']]

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, session

And how does it translate to in C#?

$item holds the results from mysql_fetch_array()

I'm not really familiar with PHP so this is all new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`$_SESSION` is a superglobal that stores session data in an associative array, see http://php.net/session.

In your example, the value at `$_SESSION['sessionName']` is apparently an array itself, which is indexed into with the value of `$item['rowName']` which smells like a string.

To simplify the expression, you could define these variables:

```
$sessionName = $_SESSION['sessionName'];
$rowName = $item['rowName'];
```

And then we could say that your example code is equivalent to

```
$sessionName[$rowName]
```

Comment: Ah thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. Anyway, seems like I need to use hashtables in .Net since things seem to work a bit different. Thanks for the time. :)

Comment: Yes, hashtable sounds about right. All PHP arrays are "associative arrays", which I believe is a synonym for "hash tables". They have keys, which can be integers or strings, and map each key to a value. You may want to read http://php.net/array